# Is it worth studying linguistics if your goal is to simply improve your communication?

Tags: linguistics

My goal in studying modern grammar has been to improve my ability to communicate (both verbally and in writing). I am having a problem in that no matter what I study, I cannot help going down linguistic rabbit holes. I might be simply trying to understand what a verb is, but it can end up taking me months because of all the different aspects of verbs that I find to be necessary to understand the concept from a linguistic standpoint.

Does anyone have advice on whether linguistic understanding is helpful for my current goal?

Is there a more practical way to utilize modern grammar?

Comment: The  question  is  out  off topic here.  you may  try  on Linguist  stack exchange

Comment: Most native-speaking Anglophones communicate reasonably happily and clearly without ever having heard of Pullum, Quirk, McCawley....

Comment: @Englishmonger Why is it off topic here? This is a site for linguists!

Comment: @ Araucaria.I think  it  is  a  broad and  opinion based  question.Much  might  be  said  on both  sides.Linguistic site  is  better  suited  to  questions  of  this king.You may  have  different  opinion and you may answer this question

Comment: @ 0Kk 41.Your  question does  not  show  that  your  English  is  bad.How  can you  write  such  a  big question without knowing the different  shades  of  a  verb?.If  you want  to  be  an expert  in  Lingjuistics and 
want  to become a good speaker and writer , the  study of  linguistics  will  surely  help you  realize your  dream

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for education advice.

Comment: @Araucaria It's asking about educational approaches, not about word choice, grammaticality of a specific construction, punctuation. Crossword puzzles, also very much English-linguists-related, are likewise off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth People should stop misinforming readers to the tune that EL&U isn’t for linguistics questions (albeit English related ones). That kind of misinformation is harmful. I don’t care either way about whether this q remains open.

Comment: @Englishmonger People should stop misinforming readers to the tune that EL&U isn’t for linguistics questions (albeit English related ones). That kind of misinformation is harmful. Kindly refrain from giving that impression.

Comment: @Araucaria That's using 'linguistics' in a disingenuous way. I could find a definition that licenses inclusion of just about anything using English. "Which type of alphabet blocks are the best for an intelligent 2-year-old?" The majority view on [Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/where-does-it-say-that-resources-are-off-topic-on-main) was that resources were off-topic, and a request for 'a more practical way to [master the language]' is certainly a request for resources. The answer is, as ever, a tailored course suitable for OP. Taking years. With texts A, then B....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR - To get better at not sounding foreign in English, first, by far, emphasize quantity of practice, speaking/listening.reading/writing English. Then learn rules about how to form sentences/phrases properly. And then learn principles of general linguistics. Once you have a proficient ability in a language the great majority of getting better is masses of vocabulary and idioms, followed by slow incremental improvement of accent.

---

I think you are really looking for how to speak/write English with fewer errors or to get across ideas in English like a native speaker does, with all the idioms and shortcuts that native speakers use.

This is a matter of language learning.

Children learn a language pretty well before even starting formal education. Sure, they may not be proficient in learning the future perfect, but they have the accent down perfectly and know when to use 'a' and 'an', though they may not be aware of what exactly the rule is.

It's more difficult for adults to learn a foreign language and one method to help is learning rules explicitly. It gives a mental framework for producing grammatical patterns when you just don't have enough repetitive experience to make it stick naturally.

But linguistics is a theoretical enterprise. It studies how languages in general work and how to help formulate patterns that all languages have and patterns that one language may have that others don't.

Linguistics is certainly relevant, to help you formulate rules you can remember to apply deliberately. You don't want to ignore it. But it is not the first thing you want to use when learning a language.

And specific rules for English grammar (which are sometimes learned in a general linguistics course) are very helpful for producing accurate English.
But you will probably get better with more mundane things like practice, or listening/reading a lot and absorbing rules implicitly.

Comment: @ Mitch.I can not expect  a  better  answer for  a  question  of  this kind.I am upvoting your answer

Comment: @Englishmonger How can you upvote an answer for a question you have already clearly said is clearly off-topic?

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth. This type  of  questions  are  usually  asked  on Linguistic stack exchange.Sometimes, they  are migrated to the  sister sites  by the  moderators.If  I had  asked the  question myself, it  would  have  been onhold now.Anyhow, Mitch gave  a  good  answer and upvoted it.Do  you  really  believe  that  the  question belongs in the site?